# Magento 1.8 site using a custom theme... but not set in admin panel

Tags: magento-1.8, theme

I have recently taken over looking after a **Magento var. 1.8** site and I want to be able to change the theme that the site is using (to be able to propose changes to the boss!)

I know the theme is currently in: `app/design/frontend/<company>/<company>` and `skin/frontend/<company>/<company>`.

I was expecting to see a Theme override in the admin panel, but all the theme options are set to default... so how does Magento know which theme to use!?

I have tried 'grep-ing' the files for some sort of override that has been set... But this has proved fruitless.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after much more digging I found out where the theme was set...

`System -> Design` not in the `System -> Configuration` as I previously expected!